# How to tell a `whereHas` query that the sub-query table is inside antoher database (multi-tenancy)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant

I use `Laravel tenancy - multi-tenant` library to make my application multi tenant as each organization should have its own database. This works fine so far as it automatically recognizes the tenant so searched for the user in the correct db.

Though when i, for example try to do a `whereHas` query like:

```
  // hostname is a system db table
  $userQuery = User::query();  // This is a tenant db table
  $userQuery->whereHas('hostname', function ($q) {
    $q->where('id', 1);
  });
  $users = $userQuery->get();
```

eloquent searches for the `hostnames` table in the same db as the `users` table.

**error**

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '721d9894276846dbb20d36ff83c46fb3.hostnames' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `hostnames` where `users`.`hostname_id` = `hostnames`.`id` and `id` = 1 and `hostnames`.`deleted_at` is null))'
```

The folowing relation works fine:

```
  Username::first()->hostname
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel;

class User extends TenantModel
{
  public function hostname() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Hostname'); }
}
```

**Hostname.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Traits\UsesSystemConnection;

class Hostname extends \Hyn\Tenancy\Models\Hostname
{
  public function user() { return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'hostname_id'); }
}
```

Note that this User - Hostname relation thing is just an example. I experience the same issue for each `whereHas` query that uses tables from 2 databases.

How can i "tell" the whereHas query that the related table in another db? i only experience this issue with `whereHas` queries (at least for now, didn't try all possible query types off course)

Comment: Isn't hostnames a table that belongs into the system database?

Comment: Hostname yes as you can see in my examples, the user is saved in the tenant db

Comment: Hey, I've been researching a bit and it's currently [not possible](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-wherehas-across-two-databases) to run a `whereHas` across tables of two different databases natively with Laravel. I don't know your exact tenant setup but this [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24398#issuecomment-539166058) might help you getting that solved.

Answer (score 1):

what I propose is to create a new UsesTenantConnection, where you establish a new function that returns the name of the table with the tenant database

To do this you must create a Trait in **"app/Traits/UsesTenantConnection.php"**

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection;

trait UsesTenantConnection
{
    public function getConnectionName()
    {
        return app(Connection::class)->tenantName();
    }

    public function getTable(): string
    {
        $config = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection::class)->configuration();

        if (str_starts_with(parent::getTable(), $config['database']))
            return parent::getTable();

        return "{$config['database']}." . parent::getTable(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to automate the connection to the system database, this post can help you
https://medium.com/@bkintanar/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-system-and-tenant-databases-29be57f7a27e